# Format output as comma separated list instead of nested arrays

Tags: php

I am trying a team making php function which create random teams but the problem is I am getting output in array format and I want it in comma format.

Here is my code:

```
$candidates = array(aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff);

function getTeam($candidates, $team_size = 3)
{
    shuffle($candidates);
    return array_chunk($candidates, $team_size);
}

$ss=print_r(getTeam($candidates));
```

I am getting output in following format:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => cc
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => dd
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => bb
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => aa
        )

)
```

but I want output in below format

```
aa,cc,dd

ee,aa,cc
```

Comment: If CSV is what you’re after, you can write to a file using fputcsv and read the contents of the file to a string. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this solution?

```
<?php
$candidates = array(
    "aa",
    "bb",
    "cc",
    "dd",
    "ee",
    "ff"
);
function getTeam($candidates, $team_size = 3)
{
    shuffle($candidates);
    return array_map(function($chunk){
        return implode(",", $chunk);
    }, array_chunk($candidates, $team_size));
}

$ss = print_r(getTeam($candidates));
```

The output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => aa,dd,cc
    [1] => ee,ff,bb
)
```

You can try it here: https://3v4l.org/W5LdC

If you want the output like this:

```
cc,ee,dd
aa,ff,bb
```

Check this code: https://3v4l.org/vghfm

Comment: thanks sir but i am looking output that is not in array foramt i need output in simple way like aa,dd,cc and ee,ff,bb

Answer (score 0):

You can glue the items of an array together using [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) (in other languages often called `join`).
The output of this function is a string. You can use anything you want as *glue*, as for example a comma and space;

```php
<?php

$array = array('aa', 'bb', 'cc');
$string = implode(", ", $array);

var_dump($string);
```

Outputs;

> string(10) "aa, bb, cc"